# Как проверить является ли шаблонный параметр класса числом с плавающей точкой c++17?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Как проверить является ли шаблонный параметр класса числом с плавающей точкой c++17?

К примеру, есть класс

```
template<typename T>
class Test
{
    
};
```

как проверить на этапе компиляции что T является double или float ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если компилятор концепты не понимает, то, например, так:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>
```

Можно также воткнуть в код

```
static_assert(is_floating_point<T>::value);
```

или

```
static_assert(is_floating_point_v<T>);
```

А если понимает -

```
typename<floating_point T>
```

или

```
template<typename T> requires floating_point<T>
```

должно хватить.

Ну, а если нужен разный код для разных типов, то можно использовать `if constexpr` - типа такого

```
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    X() {
        if constexpr (is_floating_point_v<T>)
        {
            cout << "Yes\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "No\n";
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    X<int> t;
    X<double> z;
}
```